# PE header - New Section - How to calculate OEP address in memory?

Tags: c++, header, stub, portable-executable, entry-point

I just succeeded in adding a section and some code to a pe file (in this case my proxy.exe) in Windows 10. I also changed the entrypoint to the beginning of my new section. When i run the patched .exe my stub gets called and i hear a high frequency Beep (i tested with a beep first), so far so good.

But now i want to return to the OEP. But **how can i calculate the address my oep will have in memory**?
I thought about that problem and i came up with a ?solution?:

Count the Rsize of all sections except the one i freshly added, then i get the address of my stub in memory (delta offset) and subtract the total section size from it. Now i should be at the beginning of the .text section in memory. Afterwards i add the offset for the oep and thats it.

**Will that way work or did i make a mistake?Is there another, probably easier way? And what about dlls, is there a difference for the whole procedure?**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlRKS.png <- Picture of stub

Much thanks in advance! ;)

Comment: What operating system?  My understanding is that the placement of an executable depends on the O.S (if there is one).

Comment: Oh i forgot to metion that sorry - Windows 10. *edited post

Answer (score 0):

With OEP I guess you imply fixing IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER. AddressOfEntryPoint.

Ok if I have got it correctly, then you will take the IP -> subtract the offset with the expected  RVA (related virtual address) to get the loaded address of the module and add it to the OEP's RVA to get the real address of the entry point. 
If you do the maths right this should work.

I dont have commenting privileges yet I think it should go in as a comment rather than answer as I havent tried exactly this thing but it is a proposal, which is similar to what a compiler will do for the binary.

OEP is an RVA, during injection you have the ORIG_RVA and the injected_RVA that you have substituted. In your injection logic just add

offset:push orig_rva.

Then for the offset add a relocation entry in the PE's relocation table. The loader will do the rest.